# Binding the headertext, paragraph text, and a button with the each Image using XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to bind a header text,paragraph text and a button with each Image using XML.
So each image should hold one header text, one paragraph text and one button that should bind data from XML.

So with each Image the header text,paragraph text and button should also be fade in and fade out.
And the button should have the call back of that particular image to which it belongs.

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
    <img id="imageSlide" alt="" src="" width="250px" />
    <h2> </h2>
    <p></p>
<button>Learn More</button>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $(function() {
    //Local XML Data
    var slideXML = "<rss version='2.0'><channel>";
    slideXML += "<title>IMAGES</title>";
    slideXML += "<images>";
    slideXML += "<image>http://www.academy-florists.com/images/shop/thumbnails%5CValentines_Day_flowers.jpg</image>";
    slideXML += "<image>http://www.everythingbuttheprincess.com/assets/images/babies-in-bloom-fuchsia-flower_thumbnail.jpg</image>";
    slideXML += "<image>http://www.behok.ru/i/a/cat/gerbera.jpg</image>";
    slideXML += "<image>http://www.thebutterflygrove.com/images/thumbnails/0/200/200/thumbnail_flower-decor-makpk.jpg</image>";
    slideXML += "<image>http://gameinfestedent.com/gallery_photo/medium_image/image1322820610_MainPurpleOrchids3_1a.jpg</image>";
    slideXML += "</images>";
    slideXML += "</channel></rss>";

    //Parse XML content
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(slideXML);
    var $xmldata = $(xmlDoc);

    //Find Total No of Image
    var maximages = ($xmldata.find("images").find("image").length);


    $(function() {
        //FadeIn/FadeOut Image on Set Time Interval on Slide
        setInterval(Slider, 2500);
    });

    var prevIndex = 0;

    function Slider() {
        $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            var shuffleIndex = Math.round((Math.random() * (maximages - 1)));
            if (prevIndex == shuffleIndex) {
                if (prevIndex >= (maximages - 1)) {
                    shuffleIndex--;
                } else {
                    shuffleIndex++;
                }
            }
            prevIndex = shuffleIndex;
            $("#panel").fadeIn("slow").css('background', '#000');

            var imgurl = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + shuffleIndex + ")").text();
            $(this).attr('src', imgurl).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the button supposed to lead to?

Comment: @ Christopher: Hi, Can you please arrange your script in my script. I am unable to bind it.

Comment: it's all added up at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change up your XML to something like this

```
<rss version='2.0'>
    <channel>
        <title>IMAGES</title>
        <images>
            <image id="1">
                <src>http://www.academy-florists.com/images/shop/thumbnails%5CValentines_Day_flowers.jpg</src>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[
                        <h2>Foo</h2>
                        <p>Stuff</p>
                    ]]>
                </text>
                <callback>Button Callback stuff</callback>
            </image>
            <image id="2">
                <src>http://www.everythingbuttheprincess.com/assets/images/babies-in-bloom-fuchsia-flower_thumbnail.jpg</src>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[
                        <h2>Foo</h2>
                        <p>Stuff</p>
                    ]]>
                </text>
                <callback>Button Callback stuff</callback>
            </image>
            <image id="3">
                <src>http://www.behok.ru/i/a/cat/gerbera.jpg</src>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[
                        <h2>Foo</h2>
                        <p>Stuff</p>
                    ]]>
                </text>
                <callback>Button Callback stuff</callback>
            </image>
            <image id="4">
                <src>http://www.thebutterflygrove.com/images/thumbnails/0/200/200/thumbnail_flower-decor-makpk.jpg</src>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[
                        <h2>Foo</h2>
                        <p>Stuff</p>
                    ]]>
                </text>
                <callback>Button Callback stuff</callback>
            </image>
            <image id="5">
                <src>http://gameinfestedent.com/gallery_photo/medium_image/image1322820610_MainPurpleOrchids3_1a.jpg</src>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[
                        <h2>Foo</h2>
                        <p>Stuff</p>
                    ]]>
                </text>
                <callback>Button Callback stuff</callback>  
            </image>
        </images>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Then after that, your JavaScript would hold all of the variables like this

```
        var currentImage = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + shuffleIndex + ")");
        var imgurl = currentImage.find("src").text();
        var imgText = currentImage.find("text").text();
        var imgButton = currentImage.find("callback").text();
```

and HTML

```
<div id="panel">
<img id="imageSlide" alt="" src="" width="250px" />
<div id="text">
    <!-- changed to all encompassing div -->
</div>
<button>Learn More</button>
</div>​
```

all in all, combining all of this, your whole script would look like the following

```
$(function() {
slideXML = "<rss version='2.0'>";
slideXML += "<channel>";
slideXML += "       <title>IMAGES</title>";
slideXML += "       <images>";
slideXML += "           <image id='1'>";
slideXML += "               <src>http://www.academy-florists.com/images/shop/thumbnails%5CValentines_Day_flowers.jpg</src>";
slideXML += "               <text>";
slideXML += "                   <![CDATA[";
slideXML += "                       <h2>Foo</h2>";
slideXML += "                       <p>Stuff</p>";
slideXML += "                   ]]>";
slideXML += "               </text>";
slideXML += "               <callback>Button Callback stuff</callback>";
slideXML += "           </image>";
slideXML += "           <image id='2'>";
slideXML += "               <src>http://www.everythingbuttheprincess.com/assets/images/babies-in-bloom-fuchsia-flower_thumbnail.jpg</src>";
slideXML += "               <text>";
slideXML += "                   <![CDATA[";
slideXML += "                       <h2>Foo</h2>";
slideXML += "                       <p>Stuff</p>";
slideXML += "                   ]]>";
slideXML += "               </text>";
slideXML += "               <callback>Button Callback stuff</callback>";
slideXML += "           </image>";
slideXML += "           <image id='3'>";
slideXML += "               <src>http://www.behok.ru/i/a/cat/gerbera.jpg</src>";
slideXML += "               <text>";
slideXML += "                   <![CDATA[";
slideXML += "                       <h2>Foo</h2>";
slideXML += "                       <p>Stuff</p>";
slideXML += "                   ]]>";
slideXML += "               </text>";
slideXML += "               <callback>Button Callback stuff</callback>";
slideXML += "           </image>";
slideXML += "           <image id='4'>";
slideXML += "               <src>http://www.thebutterflygrove.com/images/thumbnails/0/200/200/thumbnail_flower-decor-makpk.jpg</src>";
slideXML += "               <text>";
slideXML += "                   <![CDATA[";
slideXML += "                       <h2>Foo</h2>";
slideXML += "                       <p>Stuff</p>";
slideXML += "                   ]]>";
slideXML += "               </text>";
slideXML += "               <callback>Button Callback stuff</callback>";
slideXML += "           </image>";
slideXML += "           <image id='5'>";
slideXML += "               <src>http://gameinfestedent.com/gallery_photo/medium_image/image1322820610_MainPurpleOrchids3_1a.jpg</src>";
slideXML += "               <text>";
slideXML += "                   <![CDATA[";
slideXML += "                       <h2>Foo</h2>";
slideXML += "                       <p>Stuff</p>";
slideXML += "                   ]]>";
slideXML += "               </text>";
slideXML += "               <callback>Button Callback stuff</callback>  ";
slideXML += "           </image>";
slideXML += "       </images>";
slideXML += "   </channel>";
slideXML += "</rss>";

    //Parse XML content
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(slideXML);
    var $xmldata = $(xmlDoc);

    //Find Total No of Image
    var maximages = ($xmldata.find("images").find("image").length);     

    $(function() {
        //FadeIn/FadeOut Image on Set Time Interval on Slide
        setInterval(Slider, 2500);
    });

    var prevIndex = 0;

    function Slider() {
        $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            var shuffleIndex = Math.round((Math.random() * (maximages - 1)));
            if (prevIndex == shuffleIndex) {
                if (prevIndex >= (maximages - 1)) {
                    shuffleIndex--;
                } else {
                    shuffleIndex++;
                }
            }
            prevIndex = shuffleIndex;
            $("#panel").fadeIn("slow").css('background', '#000');
            var currentImage = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + shuffleIndex + ")");
            var imgurl = currentImage.find("src").text();
            var imgHeader = currentImage.find("text").text();
            var imgButton = currentImage.find("callback").text();
            $(this).attr('src', imgurl).fadeIn("slow");
            $("#text").html(imgHeader);
            $("#panel button").text(imgButton);
        });
    }
})
```